# How to save collapsed state in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a toggle button where when the button is clicked, the sidebar will collapse, and when the toggle button is clicked again, the sidebar will return to normal. I want to save the state in local storage, but I'm having problems with how to keep the state in local storage; the method I'm currently using doesn't save that state. What is the correct way to store state in local storage so that when the sidebar collapses, and the page is reloaded, the sidebar will still collapse?

```HTML
<div id="sidebar"
    class="c-sidebar c-sidebar-dark c-sidebar-fixed c-sidebar-sm-show sidebar" >
  <button id="header-toggler" 
      class="c-sidebar-minimizer c-class-toggler header-toggler" 
      type="button" data-target="_parent" data-class="c-sidebar-minimized">
  </button>
  <div class="c-sidebar-brand maximized">
    <img style="max-width: 100px;" 
        src="{{asset('images/brand/logo-text-white.png') }}" alt="GhoCalls Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="c-sidebar-brand minimized">
    <img style="max-width: 56px;" 
        class="p-1" src="{{asset('images/brand/logo-white.png') }}" 
        alt="GhoCalls Logo">
  </div>
  <ul class="c-sidebar-nav">
    <li class="c-sidebar-nav-item">
      <a class="c-sidebar-nav-link" href="#">
        <div class="mr-4 icon">
          <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
        </div>
        Dashboard
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
var sidebarArea  = document.getElementById("sidebar");
var headerToggle = document.getElementById("header-toggler");

if (localStorage.getItem("collapsed") === "true") {
    sidebarArea.classList.add("c-sidebar-minimized");
} else {
    sidebarArea.classList.remove("c-sidebar-minimized");
}

headerToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (sidebarArea.classList.contains("c-sidebar-minimized")) {
        localStorage.setItem("collapsed", "true");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("collapsed", "false");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **On click, change class**

On the click event, the class never changes, so the `if` condition never changes, therefore localStorage never changes.

Add a line to update class before the lines for `localStorage.setItem`:

```
headerToggle.addEventListener("click", function () {

    // NEW
    // SET STATE - UI
    sidebarArea.classList.toggle("c-sidebar-minimized");

    // SET STATE - localStorage
    if (sidebarArea.classList.contains("c-sidebar-minimized")) {
        localStorage.setItem("collapsed", "true");
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("collapsed", "false");
    }
        
});
```

Comment: I have tried it but have not succeeded in saving the state in local storage

Comment: Well, it works for me: https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/oNmrvOe --- I simply pasted your code, observed the issue of localStorage "collapsed" not updating. It was fixed upon adding the single new line from my answer; localStorage "collapsed" toggled with each toggle click. Perhaps something is wrong with your implementation that we cannot see? In any case, I propose my answer should be marked as correct for the given issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It should indeed work. I suspect there is something wrong with my code elsewhere. Btw, thank you very much for the answer you have given. @kalnode